# Call to a member function text() on string Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel

I want scrape multiple texts on the site and story in a array or different variables would be better.

```
        $text = $browser->visit('/')
        //->pause(10000)
        ->waitForText('Login')
        ->pause(1000)
        ->waitfor('#ember15')
        ->text('#ember15')
        ->text('#ember22')
        ->text('#ember29')
        ->text('#ember36')
        ->text('#ember43');
```

That's what I am doing but it's giving me this error "Call to a member function text() on string".
I want to just store multiple text in an array or string. I tried to create multiple tests but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that text() returns the text that you're looking for immediately instead of the Browser object, so you're interrupting your chain at the first text() call.

In order for this to work the way you want I think you'll have to do something like:

```
$page = $browser->visit('/')->waitForText('Login')->pause(1000)->waitFor('#ember15');
$text = [];
$text[] = $page->text('#ember15');
$text[] = $page->text('#ember22');
```

And so on...